# Trying to use notifier in an event Subscriber

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm learnig the event Subscriber on Symfony, my idea is when I create a new blog post, I want to send a notification. I'm already able to get the last entity created.
I've added to code to get the Symfony notifier and be able to send a notification on Disocrd. I currently have the following code :

```
class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            AfterEntityPersistedEvent::class => ['setBlogPostSlug'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param AfterEntityPersistedEvent $event
     * @param ChatterInterface $chatter
     * @return void
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Notifier\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function setBlogPostSlug(AfterEntityPersistedEvent $event)
    {
        $chatter = new Chatter();
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();

        if (!($entity instanceof Blog)) {
            return;
        }

        $message = (new ChatMessage('You got a new invoice for 15 EUR.'));
            // if not set explicitly, the message is send to the
            // default transport (the first one configured)
        $chatter->send($message);

    }
}
```

But when I run the code I have the followinf error :

```
App\EventSubscriber\EasyAdminSubscriber::setBlogPostSlug(): Argument #2 ($chatter) must be of type Symfony\Component\Notifier\ChatterInterface, string given
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Do you any idea why ? And how to make things work ?

Comment: The `setBlogPostSlug` method has one argument, but the docblock annotates a second argument. On it's own, I don't think this should cause an error since docblocks aren't typically enforced. Still, might be worth deleting that second @param annotation.

Comment: I think you may also be mixing up the concepts of Symfony events and Doctrine events.  Two very different things.  Kind of hard to say without knowing how the AfterEntityPersistedEvent is being dispatched.  Nor is it clear how your chatter object could know how to send a message without at least some configuration.  It's the sort of thing you probably want to inject into your subscriber.